# How to manage the functionality of a dynamically created button with each row?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, reactjs

I am working on a sample online loans application and what I need to do is that I populate the table rows with the values I have and also each row has a button "extend" which should change the values if pressed. My problem is that the button gets created in the loop and I do not know how to make it affect the values that are also populated in the same loop, so to sum it up what I want to do is for example when value is = 10, I want to make it change to 20 if I press the button and here is what I have so far

```
export default class History extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
     extended:false // refers to having the loan extended or not
   };
 }

/* change state variable on extend button press */
  extend() {
    this.setState({
        extended: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    var items = this.props.loan;
    var that = this;
    var extendBtn = <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn small green     lighten" onClick={that.extend.bind(that)}>Extend!</a>;
    var itemslist = items.map( function(item, index) {
      var value = item.moneyDue; // Money to be paid
      var date = item.PayDay;    // Date of payment
      var days = item.daysNo;    // Number of loan days
      var extensionAmount = item.extension;
      return(
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{item.moneyBorrowed} Eur</td>
          <td>{days}</td>
          <td>{value} Eur</td>
          <td>{date}<span>{extendBtn}</span></td>
        </tr>
      );
    })

    return (
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="card blue lighten-5">
            <div class="card-content">
              <table class="bordered highlight">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th data-field="id">Amount Borrowed</th>
                    <th data-field="name">Days</th>
                    <th data-field="price">Total Due</th>
                    <th data-field="price">Payment Date</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {itemslist}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

the loan data from the parent class

```
export default class Tabs extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loan:[]
    };
  }

/* updates the state variables before passing to History */
  handler(money,daysCount,dueMoney,datePay,ext,date) {
    loanArray.push({
      moneyBorrowed:money,
      daysNo:daysCount,
      moneyDue: dueMoney,
      PayDay:datePay,
      extension:ext,
      dateMilli:date
    });
    this.setState({
      loan:loanArray
    });
   }
```

Comment: just curious, why don't you move the `itemlist` generation into another class so you can keep track of the things independently easier?

Comment: @A.Lau yeah that actually makes sense, thank you, but i still do not know how to solve the mentioned problem, can you help please?

Comment: well you move it into a class, each class can track their `this.props` and their on `onClick` functions. If it works for 1, then it should work for all. That's the beauty of using classes.

Comment: You could create the button inside of the iteration and pass on the index parameter to it. That way you know which item was clicked.

Comment: @mitchken i seem to be stuck, my mind is going through stupidity moments, im still very new with react so im very confused about everything a bit, can you give me an example, that would really clear things up very much

Comment: Can you provide your `loan` data sample?

Comment: @user3209048, Just need an example of `loan` array at least with 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

This should be quite simple to do with flux or redux.
In your situation you need to create a new function in Tabs which will set the state. For example:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loan:[]
    };
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
  }

updateState(loanData) {
    this.state = {
      loan: loanData
    };
  }
```

And you should pass this function as a prop to your History component.

```
<History updateState={this.updateState} loan={this.state.loan} />
```

Then inside your History component you should update your function to something like this:

```
extend(index){
    this.setState({
        extended: true
    });
    this.props.loan[index] = "something";
    this.props.updateState(this.props.loan);
}
```

also change this line to:

```
var extendBtn = <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn small green lighten" onClick={that.extend.bind(that, index)}>Extend!</a>;
```

Put this line inside your items.map.

This should do the trick. I don't have enough time to test the code. It maybe not fully correct.